# Redirect to another JSF page returns 404 error

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2, http-status-code-404

i'm using jsf 2.0 for my project when my `login.xhtml` page opened an i entered my username and password the page will redirect to my `firstpage.xhtml` and my page don't open and getting me 404 error.

```
public void checkLogin() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, IOException {

        if (new LoginBAO().checkLoginFaild(user)) {
            new LoginBAO().updattUserFaild(user);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "خطا در ورود", "بیشتر از  سه دفعه اشتباه اطلاعات خود را وارد کرده اید"));
        } else {
            if (!new LoginBAO().validUsername(user)) {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "خطا در ورود", "نام کاربری یا رمز عبور را اشتباه وارد کرده اید"));
            } else {
                if (new LoginBAO().validPassword(user)) {
                    new LoginBAO().updattUserFaild(user);
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "خطا در ورود", "نام کاربری یا رمز عبور را اشتباه وارد کرده اید"));
                } else {
                    new LoginBAO().updateLoginCorrect(user);
                    String uri = "firstpage.jsf";
                    ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
                    context.redirect(uri);

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

so what can i do  for this problem ?
am i change my web.xml code from this problem ?

Comment: Did you look at URL in browser's address bar? Is it a valid URL? The 404 clearly suggests it doesn't point to an existing resource. If you tell which URL exactly it should have been, then we can tell how to compose `uri`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to use an action instead of actionListener for this, since action is meant for exactly navigation. So try with

```
<p:commandButton value="Login" update="growl" action="#{login.checkLogin()}" />
```

Then change the method signature to

```
public String checkLogin()
```

Also I don't think this method needs to throw all those exceptions, if the LoginBAO-methods throws those better catch them in there.

Finally return either null or the name of the new xhtml-page to show, for example

```
if (new LoginBAO().checkLoginFaild(user)) {
        new LoginBAO().updattUserFaild(user);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "خطا در ورود", "بیشتر از  سه دفعه اشتباه اطلاعات خود را وارد کرده اید"));
        return null;
}
```

and the redirect would just be

```
return "/firstpage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
```

The ?faces-redirect=true is needed since the commandButton submits an ajax call, on which a normal navigation cannot be made.

Make sure the Faces Servlet is mapped to *.xhtml in the web.xml.

Comment: thanks a lot ,you solve my problem 
i say thank in persian :دستت درد نکنه
this language in not arabic if u want to translate it set persian
Jaqen H'ghar